# Plotting a function in an implicit formula

Tags: matlab

I want to sweep the variable `Q` from -.4 to +.4 and then plot the variable V for each individual value of `Q`. 
`0.188Q^2+.44*V^2*Q+.0221+V^4+(.2-1.05^2)*V^2=0`
But I am not sure how to go about solving this problem, as I have never faced something like this before. Can someone please advice on how to code this?

Answer (score 1):

This is  job for `ezplot`!

As you have your function in implicit form, unless you write it in explicit form (i.e. y=..) you can not use plot. But you can use `ezplot`!

just do

```
ezplot('x.*0.188*x.^2+.44*y.^2*x+.0221+y.^4+(.2-1.05^2)*y^2',[-4 4])
```